# Text length returning wrong length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am auto resizing the text font size which is working fine but I also want to calculate the text length, but I am getting wrong length. Here is the [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/fuy50zde/1/) code. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
var len=$(targetid).text().length;
    
    alert(len);
```

I am using `text().length` method but I am getting wrong values.

```
$('.jtextfill').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 },'h1');
$('.jtextfill2').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 },'h2');
$('.jtextfill3').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36 },'h3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text() method is returning the text within the h1, h2 and h3 tags, as well as the spaces and newline characters that surround them.

You need to make sure that you trim() before testing the length:

```
var len=$(targetid).text().trim().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the leading and trailing spaces created by the empty text nodes, you can trim the text to remove them

```
var len=$(targetid).text().trim().length;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gxd4ack6/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem  you have is that it's counting spaces too, you should trim the text before reading length.

```
$($(targetid).text()).trim().length
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.text()` includes the whitespace that surrounds the the `span` elements that are children of the `.jtextfill` elements.

### Option 1 - Remove the whitepace ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwh560tu/)):

```
<h1 id="h1" class='jtextfill'><span>Sample1</span></h1>
<h2 id="h2" class='jtextfill2'><span>Sample2</span></h2>
<h3 id="h3" class='jtextfill3'><span>Sample3</span></h3>
```

### Option 2 - `$.trim` the whitespace ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rwk0w2c/)):

```
var len = $.trim($(targetid).text()).length;
```

**Modern-browser alternative:**

```
var len = $(targetid).text().trim().length;
```